# Simple foreach search within multidimensional array

Tags: php, foreach

I have  the following array:

```
$dates[] = array(
    'Sunday'  => '13 Jul 2014',
    'Monday'  => '14 Jul 2014',
    'Tuesday' => '15 Jul 2014',
);
```

I would like to search the array to see if there is a match with today. I have set today up as a variable as follows:

```
$today = date('d M Y', strtotime('today'));
```

And I am attempting to search for a match using a simple foreach:

```
foreach ($dates as $day => $date) {
    if ($today == $date) {
        echo 'match';
    } else {
        echo 'no match';
    }
}
```

However, this always returns 'no match'. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Live version here: http://viper-7.com/4INcaz

Comment: Have you specified a correct timezone? (Edit: After further thinking, it may not affect that much...)

Comment: yes, $today = '13 Jul 2014'

Comment: Have you tried adding `echo $date." != ".$today;` inside the loop, for debugging?

Comment: look at this: $dates[] = array( ... Here some mistake. Do you mean $dates = array() (without []?)

Comment: yes, I get an Array to string conversion error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your array:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'Sunday'  => '13 Jul 2014',
        'Monday'  => '14 Jul 2014',
        'Tuesday' => '15 Jul 2014',
    )
);
```

because you assigned the array to `$dates[]`. You should do:

```
foreach ($dates[0] as $day => $date) {
    if ($today == $date) {
        echo 'match';
    } else {
        echo 'no match';
    }
}
```

or this:

```
$dates = array(
    'Sunday'  => '13 Jul 2014',
    'Monday'  => '14 Jul 2014',
    'Tuesday' => '15 Jul 2014',
);
```